# AngularJS ng-repeat double td

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've looked around and was able to find similar questions to mine but not the same. This might be a realy noobie question but I have no idea how to do this. I'm using ng-repeat to show 4 checkboxes like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="type in dataType">
  <td><checkbox ng-model="type.checked"></checkbox> {{type.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

This gives me 4 checkboxes in one row. But what i would like is for the first two checkboxes to be side by side. So 2x td inside one tr.
However when i change the code to

```
<tr ng-repeat="type in dataType">
  <td><checkbox ng-model="type.checked"></checkbox> {{type.name}}</td>
  <td><checkbox ng-model="type.checked"></checkbox> {{type.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

It just multiplies the checkboxes and i end up with 2 rows and 8 checkboxes. So how do i get ng-repeat to change checkbox 2 into the next iteration of type?

Comment: Your first snippet of code should be giving you one row per checkbox. Is that what you are seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always restructure the variables, for example:

```
$scope.rows = [ [dataType[0], dataType[1]], [dataType[2], dataType[3]] ];
```

And then:

```
<tr ng-repeat="type in rows">
  <td><checkbox ng-model="type[0].checked"></checkbox> {{type[0].name}}</td>
  <td><checkbox ng-model="type[1].checked"></checkbox> {{type[1].name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This works, and i will be using this for now. The only problem I have with it is that it requires manual maintenance if an extra dataType is added. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: You're welcome! That was just an idea to get you started: basically, I wanted to say that sometimes it's better to restructure the app data instead of looking some creative one-line hackish solutions (imagine looking at it in a year or so). And about manual grouping, it doesn't have to be manual, a simple for loop can group them nicely `for (var i = 0; i < dataType.length; i+=2) {rows.push( [dataType[i], dataType[i+1] ); }` for example.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, even though it's so simple. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a perfect solution, it should do the trick:

```
<tr ng-repeat="type in dataType" ng-if="$index <= 1">
  <td><checkbox ng-model="type.checked"></checkbox> {{type.name}}</td>
  <td><checkbox ng-model="type.checked"></checkbox> {{type.name}}</td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="type in dataType" ng-if="$index > 1">
  <td><checkbox ng-model="type.checked"></checkbox> {{type.name}}</td>
  <td><checkbox ng-model="type.checked"></checkbox> {{type.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

I'm researching whether or not it can be done with `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`.

As mentioned by Alejandro, another solution is this:

```
<tr>
  <td><checkbox ng-model="dataType[0].checked"></checkbox> {{dataType[0].name}}</td>
  <td><checkbox ng-model="dataType[1].checked"></checkbox> {{dataType[1].name}}</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><checkbox ng-model="dataType[2].checked"></checkbox> {{dataType[2].name}}</td>
  <td><checkbox ng-model="dataType[3].checked"></checkbox> {{dataType[3].name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That will still create 4 rows.

Comment: I was going the same way... just change a little and you have it

Comment: anyway..... if they are ALWAYS 4... why using ng repeat when you just need to write the structure and refer with ng-model to dataType[x]?

Comment: Well for now there are 4, and I will not be adding anymore, but in the future it might become more. I could also just lose ng-repeat and write 4 td's. Not that much duplication and alot less trouble. But I always prefer finding the DRY if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="_ in dataType" ng-if="$even">
    <td ng-repeat="type in dataType.slice($parent.$index, $parent.$index + 2)"><checkbox ng-model="type.checked"></checkbox> {{type.name}}</td>
</tr>
```